# Rails reading in and rendering seperate html doc, need <base> to only apply to the read in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, head, base-tag

I am writing a mobile web application using Rails and jQuery mobile. I am reading all of my data at runtime from Amazon AWS S3 using HTTParty.

One of the screens that I need to render is just straight html, which can and usually does have images embedded into it which are hosted in the same folder on S3. This is where my problem is. I can easily pull in the html with HTTParty and use the html_safe option to render it, but the images don't render as they are relative path names. So I have been trying to find a way around this.

I have tried multiple things, but I have mainly been looking into using an html  tag to get the images to point to the right location. The problem is that I cant specify a base tag and then have other links on the page, because they then use that same base and the links are not pointing atand the correct location. So I looked into framesets and frame and pointing the base tag only at the frame, which I believe I used correctly, but to no avail. I tried using  but to no avail.

So basically I am looking for a way that I can set the base for relative path names in an html string that I read in from S3, if that wasn't clear. I am open to any suggestions! And thanks in advance for even reading and try to solve this very specific problem!

Oh and one more thing, when I look at the page with Firebug, the first line in the header is a base tag with href set to the current page. I can't find out where it is coming from but I am guessing rails is throwing it in there? I don't know if this matters since I then put another base tag below it with the yield :intro_base? Or is that one of my problems since there is a conflict there?

And then there was code:
My 'intro' method:

```
def intro
@intros = []
@app_config.intro_screens.each do |intro_screen|
  intro_screen_response =
    ApplicationController.get("#{@diandr_url}/#{intro_screen['filename']}.html")
  @intros << intro_screen_response.body
end
@intros.reverse!
@intros_length = @intros.length
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
end
```

My 'intro.html.erb' file:

```
<% page_num = params[:id].to_i %>

<% content_for :intro_base do %>
  <base href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/our_bucket_name<%=@dir_url%>/" target="intro" />
<% end %>  


<% content_for :mobile_header do %>
  *some jQuery mobile paging and header stuff is in here, shouldn't matter*
<% end %> 

<% content_for :mobile_content do %>

  <!-- <iframe src=<%= @intros[page_num] %> height="100%" width="100%">  -->
  <!--   <p> This browser does not support iframes </p> -->
  <!-- </iframe>  -->

  <frameset cols="100%">
    <frame name="intro" <%= @intros[page_num].html_safe %>
  </frameset>

<% end %>
```

My layout's header:

```
<head>
<title> our Mobile App </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- These are the jQuery Mobile scripts --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"> 
</script>
<%= yield :intro_base %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "master" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```